# How do I delete rows with same hour and minute in timeseries data based on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

The pandas dataframe has the following columns:

```
df.columns= ['Date','Hour','Minute','Voltage']
```

I have the data for a month. So, each timestamp has 30 values over the month and the data is for each 5-minute interval. I want to remove rows with the same Hour and Minute for all days if the data satisfies the following condition:

```
df['Voltage'].isna()>5
```

So, if the dataset has NA values of voltage for more than 5 rows with the same hour and minute, I want to delete all rows with that timestamp. For example, if at 7:30, we have 10 NA values for voltage, we have to remove all rows with Hour=7 and Minute=30. How do I solve this problem?
This a sample of the dataset(2 days of data):

```
{'Date': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 1,
  11: 1,
  12: 1,
  13: 1,
  14: 1,
  15: 1,
  16: 1,
  17: 1,
  18: 1,
  19: 1,
  20: 1,
  21: 1,
  22: 1,
  23: 1,
  24: 1,
  25: 1,
  26: 1,
  27: 1,
  28: 1,
  29: 1,
  30: 1,
  31: 1,
  32: 1,
  33: 1,
  34: 1,
  35: 1,
  36: 1,
  37: 1,
  38: 1,
  39: 1,
  40: 1,
  41: 1,
  42: 1,
  43: 1,
  44: 1,
  45: 1,
  46: 1,
  47: 1,
  48: 1,
  49: 1,
  50: 1,
  51: 1,
  52: 1,
  53: 1,
  54: 1,
  55: 1,
  56: 1,
  57: 1,
  58: 1,
  59: 1,
  60: 1,
  61: 1,
  62: 1,
  63: 1,
  64: 1,
  65: 1,
  66: 1,
  67: 1,
  68: 1,
  69: 1,
  70: 1,
  71: 1,
  72: 1,
  73: 1,
  74: 1,
  75: 1,
  76: 1,
  77: 1,
  78: 1,
  79: 1,
  80: 1,
  81: 1,
  82: 1,
  83: 1,
  84: 1,
  85: 1,
  86: 1,
  87: 1,
  88: 1,
  89: 1,
  90: 1,
  91: 1,
  92: 1,
  93: 1,
  94: 1,
  95: 1,
  96: 1,
  97: 1,
  98: 1,
  99: 1,
  100: 1,
  101: 1,
  102: 1,
  103: 1,
  104: 1,
  105: 1,
  106: 1,
  107: 1,
  108: 1,
  109: 1,
  110: 1,
  111: 1,
  112: 1,
  113: 1,
  114: 1,
  115: 1,
  116: 1,
  117: 1,
  118: 1,
  119: 1,
  120: 1,
  121: 1,
  122: 1,
  123: 1,
  124: 1,
  125: 1,
  126: 1,
  127: 1,
  128: 1,
  129: 1,
  130: 1,
  131: 1,
  132: 1,
  133: 1,
  134: 1,
  135: 1,
  136: 1,
  137: 1,
  138: 1,
  139: 1,
  140: 1,
  141: 1,
  142: 1,
  143: 1,
  144: 1,
  145: 1,
  146: 1,
  147: 1,
  148: 1,
  149: 1,
  150: 1,
  151: 1,
  152: 1,
  153: 1,
  154: 1,
  155: 1,
  156: 2,
  157: 2,
  158: 2,
  159: 2,
  160: 2,
  161: 2,
  162: 2,
  163: 2,
  164: 2,
  165: 2,
  166: 2,
  167: 2,
  168: 2,
  169: 2,
  170: 2,
  171: 2,
  172: 2,
  173: 2,
  174: 2,
  175: 2,
  176: 2,
  177: 2,
  178: 2,
  179: 2,
  180: 2,
  181: 2,
  182: 2,
  183: 2,
  184: 2,
  185: 2,
  186: 2,
  187: 2,
  188: 2,
  189: 2,
  190: 2,
  191: 2,
  192: 2,
  193: 2,
  194: 2,
  195: 2,
  196: 2,
  197: 2,
  198: 2,
  199: 2,
  200: 2,
  201: 2,
  202: 2,
  203: 2,
  204: 2,
  205: 2,
  206: 2,
  207: 2,
  208: 2,
  209: 2,
  210: 2,
  211: 2,
  212: 2,
  213: 2,
  214: 2,
  215: 2,
  216: 2,
  217: 2,
  218: 2,
  219: 2,
  220: 2,
  221: 2,
  222: 2,
  223: 2,
  224: 2,
  225: 2,
  226: 2,
  227: 2,
  228: 2,
  229: 2,
  230: 2,
  231: 2,
  232: 2,
  233: 2,
  234: 2,
  235: 2,
  236: 2,
  237: 2,
  238: 2,
  239: 2,
  240: 2,
  241: 2,
  242: 2,
  243: 2,
  244: 2,
  245: 2,
  246: 2,
  247: 2,
  248: 2,
  249: 2,
  250: 2,
  251: 2,
  252: 2,
  253: 2,
  254: 2,
  255: 2,
  256: 2,
  257: 2,
  258: 2,
  259: 2,
  260: 2,
  261: 2,
  262: 2,
  263: 2,
  264: 2,
  265: 2,
  266: 2,
  267: 2,
  268: 2,
  269: 2,
  270: 2,
  271: 2,
  272: 2,
  273: 2,
  274: 2,
  275: 2,
  276: 2,
  277: 2,
  278: 2,
  279: 2,
  280: 2,
  281: 2,
  282: 2,
  283: 2,
  284: 2,
  285: 2,
  286: 2,
  287: 2,
  288: 2,
  289: 2,
  290: 2,
  291: 2,
  292: 2,
  293: 2,
  294: 2,
  295: 2,
  296: 2,
  297: 2,
  298: 2,
  299: 2,
  300: 2,
  301: 2,
  302: 2,
  303: 2,
  304: 2,
  305: 2,
  306: 2,
  307: 2,
  308: 2,
  309: 2,
  310: 2,
  311: 2},
 'Hour': {0: 6,
  1: 6,
  2: 6,
  3: 6,
  4: 6,
  5: 6,
  6: 6,
  7: 6,
  8: 6,
  9: 6,
  10: 6,
  11: 6,
  12: 7,
  13: 7,
  14: 7,
  15: 7,
  16: 7,
  17: 7,
  18: 7,
  19: 7,
  20: 7,
  21: 7,
  22: 7,
  23: 7,
  24: 8,
  25: 8,
  26: 8,
  27: 8,
  28: 8,
  29: 8,
  30: 8,
  31: 8,
  32: 8,
  33: 8,
  34: 8,
  35: 8,
  36: 9,
  37: 9,
  38: 9,
  39: 9,
  40: 9,
  41: 9,
  42: 9,
  43: 9,
  44: 9,
  45: 9,
  46: 9,
  47: 9,
  48: 10,
  49: 10,
  50: 10,
  51: 10,
  52: 10,
  53: 10,
  54: 10,
  55: 10,
  56: 10,
  57: 10,
  58: 10,
  59: 10,
  60: 11,
  61: 11,
  62: 11,
  63: 11,
  64: 11,
  65: 11,
  66: 11,
  67: 11,
  68: 11,
  69: 11,
  70: 11,
  71: 11,
  72: 12,
  73: 12,
  74: 12,
  75: 12,
  76: 12,
  77: 12,
  78: 12,
  79: 12,
  80: 12,
  81: 12,
  82: 12,
  83: 12,
  84: 13,
  85: 13,
  86: 13,
  87: 13,
  88: 13,
  89: 13,
  90: 13,
  91: 13,
  92: 13,
  93: 13,
  94: 13,
  95: 13,
  96: 14,
  97: 14,
  98: 14,
  99: 14,
  100: 14,
  101: 14,
  102: 14,
  103: 14,
  104: 14,
  105: 14,
  106: 14,
  107: 14,
  108: 15,
  109: 15,
  110: 15,
  111: 15,
  112: 15,
  113: 15,
  114: 15,
  115: 15,
  116: 15,
  117: 15,
  118: 15,
  119: 15,
  120: 16,
  121: 16,
  122: 16,
  123: 16,
  124: 16,
  125: 16,
  126: 16,
  127: 16,
  128: 16,
  129: 16,
  130: 16,
  131: 16,
  132: 17,
  133: 17,
  134: 17,
  135: 17,
  136: 17,
  137: 17,
  138: 17,
  139: 17,
  140: 17,
  141: 17,
  142: 17,
  143: 17,
  144: 18,
  145: 18,
  146: 18,
  147: 18,
  148: 18,
  149: 18,
  150: 18,
  151: 18,
  152: 18,
  153: 18,
  154: 18,
  155: 18,
  156: 6,
  157: 6,
  158: 6,
  159: 6,
  160: 6,
  161: 6,
  162: 6,
  163: 6,
  164: 6,
  165: 6,
  166: 6,
  167: 6,
  168: 7,
  169: 7,
  170: 7,
  171: 7,
  172: 7,
  173: 7,
  174: 7,
  175: 7,
  176: 7,
  177: 7,
  178: 7,
  179: 7,
  180: 8,
  181: 8,
  182: 8,
  183: 8,
  184: 8,
  185: 8,
  186: 8,
  187: 8,
  188: 8,
  189: 8,
  190: 8,
  191: 8,
  192: 9,
  193: 9,
  194: 9,
  195: 9,
  196: 9,
  197: 9,
  198: 9,
  199: 9,
  200: 9,
  201: 9,
  202: 9,
  203: 9,
  204: 10,
  205: 10,
  206: 10,
  207: 10,
  208: 10,
  209: 10,
  210: 10,
  211: 10,
  212: 10,
  213: 10,
  214: 10,
  215: 10,
  216: 11,
  217: 11,
  218: 11,
  219: 11,
  220: 11,
  221: 11,
  222: 11,
  223: 11,
  224: 11,
  225: 11,
  226: 11,
  227: 11,
  228: 12,
  229: 12,
  230: 12,
  231: 12,
  232: 12,
  233: 12,
  234: 12,
  235: 12,
  236: 12,
  237: 12,
  238: 12,
  239: 12,
  240: 13,
  241: 13,
  242: 13,
  243: 13,
  244: 13,
  245: 13,
  246: 13,
  247: 13,
  248: 13,
  249: 13,
  250: 13,
  251: 13,
  252: 14,
  253: 14,
  254: 14,
  255: 14,
  256: 14,
  257: 14,
  258: 14,
  259: 14,
  260: 14,
  261: 14,
  262: 14,
  263: 14,
  264: 15,
  265: 15,
  266: 15,
  267: 15,
  268: 15,
  269: 15,
  270: 15,
  271: 15,
  272: 15,
  273: 15,
  274: 15,
  275: 15,
  276: 16,
  277: 16,
  278: 16,
  279: 16,
  280: 16,
  281: 16,
  282: 16,
  283: 16,
  284: 16,
  285: 16,
  286: 16,
  287: 16,
  288: 17,
  289: 17,
  290: 17,
  291: 17,
  292: 17,
  293: 17,
  294: 17,
  295: 17,
  296: 17,
  297: 17,
  298: 17,
  299: 17,
  300: 18,
  301: 18,
  302: 18,
  303: 18,
  304: 18,
  305: 18,
  306: 18,
  307: 18,
  308: 18,
  309: 18,
  310: 18,
  311: 18},
 'Minute': {0: 0,
  1: 5,
  2: 10,
  3: 15,
  4: 20,
  5: 25,
  6: 30,
  7: 35,
  8: 40,
  9: 45,
  10: 50,
  11: 55,
  12: 0,
  13: 5,
  14: 10,
  15: 15,
  16: 20,
  17: 25,
  18: 30,
  19: 35,
  20: 40,
  21: 45,
  22: 50,
  23: 55,
  24: 0,
  25: 5,
  26: 10,
  27: 15,
  28: 20,
  29: 25,
  30: 30,
  31: 35,
  32: 40,
  33: 45,
  34: 50,
  35: 55,
  36: 0,
  37: 5,
  38: 10,
  39: 15,
  40: 20,
  41: 25,
  42: 30,
  43: 35,
  44: 40,
  45: 45,
  46: 50,
  47: 55,
  48: 0,
  49: 5,
  50: 10,
  51: 15,
  52: 20,
  53: 25,
  54: 30,
  55: 35,
  56: 40,
  57: 45,
  58: 50,
  59: 55,
  60: 0,
  61: 5,
  62: 10,
  63: 15,
  64: 20,
  65: 25,
  66: 30,
  67: 35,
  68: 40,
  69: 45,
  70: 50,
  71: 55,
  72: 0,
  73: 5,
  74: 10,
  75: 15,
  76: 20,
  77: 25,
  78: 30,
  79: 35,
  80: 40,
  81: 45,
  82: 50,
  83: 55,
  84: 0,
  85: 5,
  86: 10,
  87: 15,
  88: 20,
  89: 25,
  90: 30,
  91: 35,
  92: 40,
  93: 45,
  94: 50,
  95: 55,
  96: 0,
  97: 5,
  98: 10,
  99: 15,
  100: 20,
  101: 25,
  102: 30,
  103: 35,
  104: 40,
  105: 45,
  106: 50,
  107: 55,
  108: 0,
  109: 5,
  110: 10,
  111: 15,
  112: 20,
  113: 25,
  114: 30,
  115: 35,
  116: 40,
  117: 45,
  118: 50,
  119: 55,
  120: 0,
  121: 5,
  122: 10,
  123: 15,
  124: 20,
  125: 25,
  126: 30,
  127: 35,
  128: 40,
  129: 45,
  130: 50,
  131: 55,
  132: 0,
  133: 5,
  134: 10,
  135: 15,
  136: 20,
  137: 25,
  138: 30,
  139: 35,
  140: 40,
  141: 45,
  142: 50,
  143: 55,
  144: 0,
  145: 5,
  146: 10,
  147: 15,
  148: 20,
  149: 25,
  150: 30,
  151: 35,
  152: 40,
  153: 45,
  154: 50,
  155: 55,
  156: 0,
  157: 5,
  158: 10,
  159: 15,
  160: 20,
  161: 25,
  162: 30,
  163: 35,
  164: 40,
  165: 45,
  166: 50,
  167: 55,
  168: 0,
  169: 5,
  170: 10,
  171: 15,
  172: 20,
  173: 25,
  174: 30,
  175: 35,
  176: 40,
  177: 45,
  178: 50,
  179: 55,
  180: 0,
  181: 5,
  182: 10,
  183: 15,
  184: 20,
  185: 25,
  186: 30,
  187: 35,
  188: 40,
  189: 45,
  190: 50,
  191: 55,
  192: 0,
  193: 5,
  194: 10,
  195: 15,
  196: 20,
  197: 25,
  198: 30,
  199: 35,
  200: 40,
  201: 45,
  202: 50,
  203: 55,
  204: 0,
  205: 5,
  206: 10,
  207: 15,
  208: 20,
  209: 25,
  210: 30,
  211: 35,
  212: 40,
  213: 45,
  214: 50,
  215: 55,
  216: 0,
  217: 5,
  218: 10,
  219: 15,
  220: 20,
  221: 25,
  222: 30,
  223: 35,
  224: 40,
  225: 45,
  226: 50,
  227: 55,
  228: 0,
  229: 5,
  230: 10,
  231: 15,
  232: 20,
  233: 25,
  234: 30,
  235: 35,
  236: 40,
  237: 45,
  238: 50,
  239: 55,
  240: 0,
  241: 5,
  242: 10,
  243: 15,
  244: 20,
  245: 25,
  246: 30,
  247: 35,
  248: 40,
  249: 45,
  250: 50,
  251: 55,
  252: 0,
  253: 5,
  254: 10,
  255: 15,
  256: 20,
  257: 25,
  258: 30,
  259: 35,
  260: 40,
  261: 45,
  262: 50,
  263: 55,
  264: 0,
  265: 5,
  266: 10,
  267: 15,
  268: 20,
  269: 25,
  270: 30,
  271: 35,
  272: 40,
  273: 45,
  274: 50,
  275: 55,
  276: 0,
  277: 5,
  278: 10,
  279: 15,
  280: 20,
  281: 25,
  282: 30,
  283: 35,
  284: 40,
  285: 45,
  286: 50,
  287: 55,
  288: 0,
  289: 5,
  290: 10,
  291: 15,
  292: 20,
  293: 25,
  294: 30,
  295: 35,
  296: 40,
  297: 45,
  298: 50,
  299: 55,
  300: 0,
  301: 5,
  302: 10,
  303: 15,
  304: 20,
  305: 25,
  306: 30,
  307: 35,
  308: 40,
  309: 45,
  310: 50,
  311: 55},
 'Voltage': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0,
  20: 0.0,
  21: 0.0,
  22: 0.0,
  23: 0.31,
  24: 0.35,
  25: 0.4,
  26: 0.44,
  27: 0.53,
  28: 0.64,
  29: 0.73,
  30: 0.81,
  31: 0.89,
  32: 0.95,
  33: 1.02,
  34: 1.11,
  35: 1.19,
  36: 1.22,
  37: 1.06,
  38: 1.06,
  39: 1.11,
  40: 1.12,
  41: 1.17,
  42: 1.18,
  43: 1.25,
  44: 1.25,
  45: 1.32,
  46: 1.3,
  47: 1.46,
  48: 1.47,
  49: 1.56,
  50: 1.61,
  51: 1.63,
  52: 1.71,
  53: 1.76,
  54: 1.8,
  55: 1.87,
  56: 1.89,
  57: 2.01,
  58: 2.09,
  59: 2.05,
  60: 2.04,
  61: 1.98,
  62: 1.92,
  63: 1.99,
  64: 2.11,
  65: 2.13,
  66: 2.0,
  67: 2.1,
  68: 1.83,
  69: 2.08,
  70: 2.27,
  71: 2.27,
  72: 2.43,
  73: 2.37,
  74: 2.32,
  75: 2.24,
  76: 2.33,
  77: 2.2,
  78: 2.22,
  79: 2.16,
  80: 2.12,
  81: 2.13,
  82: 2.12,
  83: 2.08,
  84: 2.06,
  85: 2.09,
  86: 2.05,
  87: 1.99,
  88: 1.83,
  89: 1.88,
  90: 1.81,
  91: 1.8,
  92: 1.78,
  93: 1.73,
  94: 1.66,
  95: 1.69,
  96: 1.45,
  97: 1.54,
  98: 1.5,
  99: 1.56,
  100: 1.52,
  101: 1.43,
  102: 1.41,
  103: 1.34,
  104: 1.3,
  105: 1.24,
  106: 1.16,
  107: 1.08,
  108: 1.07,
  109: 1.02,
  110: 0.93,
  111: 0.69,
  112: 0.36,
  113: 0.0,
  114: 0.0,
  115: 0.0,
  116: 0.67,
  117: 0.61,
  118: 0.0,
  119: 0.4,
  120: 0.38,
  121: 0.31,
  122: 0.0,
  123: 0.0,
  124: 0.0,
  125: 0.0,
  126: 0.0,
  127: 0.0,
  128: 0.0,
  129: 0.0,
  130: 0.0,
  131: 0.0,
  132: 0.0,
  133: 0.0,
  134: 0.0,
  135: 0.0,
  136: 0.0,
  137: 0.0,
  138: 0.0,
  139: 0.0,
  140: 0.0,
  141: 0.0,
  142: 0.0,
  143: 0.0,
  144: 0.0,
  145: 0.0,
  146: 0.0,
  147: 0.0,
  148: 0.0,
  149: 0.0,
  150: 0.0,
  151: 0.0,
  152: 0.0,
  153: 0.0,
  154: 0.0,
  155: 0.0,
  156: 0.0,
  157: 0.0,
  158: 0.0,
  159: 0.0,
  160: 0.0,
  161: 0.0,
  162: 0.0,
  163: 0.0,
  164: 0.0,
  165: 0.0,
  166: 0.0,
  167: 0.0,
  168: 0.0,
  169: 0.0,
  170: 0.0,
  171: 0.0,
  172: 0.0,
  173: 0.0,
  174: 0.0,
  175: 0.0,
  176: 0.0,
  177: 0.0,
  178: 0.0,
  179: 0.0,
  180: 0.0,
  181: 0.34,
  182: 0.39,
  183: 0.46,
  184: 0.52,
  185: 0.59,
  186: 0.67,
  187: 0.72,
  188: 0.75,
  189: 0.79,
  190: 0.84,
  191: 0.78,
  192: 0.82,
  193: 0.83,
  194: 0.85,
  195: 0.87,
  196: 0.92,
  197: 0.97,
  198: 1.01,
  199: 1.05,
  200: 1.12,
  201: 1.17,
  202: 1.2,
  203: 1.24,
  204: 1.28,
  205: 1.32,
  206: 1.35,
  207: 1.4,
  208: 1.45,
  209: 1.51,
  210: 1.51,
  211: 1.53,
  212: 1.56,
  213: 1.61,
  214: 1.55,
  215: 1.66,
  216: 1.64,
  217: 1.67,
  218: 1.74,
  219: 1.63,
  220: 1.67,
  221: 1.76,
  222: 1.81,
  223: 1.86,
  224: 1.82,
  225: 1.82,
  226: 1.85,
  227: 1.81,
  228: 1.9,
  229: 1.85,
  230: 1.72,
  231: 1.88,
  232: 1.82,
  233: 1.91,
  234: 1.9,
  235: 1.96,
  236: 1.95,
  237: 1.86,
  238: 1.91,
  239: 1.85,
  240: 1.87,
  241: 1.82,
  242: 1.75,
  243: 1.71,
  244: 1.67,
  245: 1.66,
  246: 1.61,
  247: 1.64,
  248: 1.6,
  249: 1.48,
  250: 1.51,
  251: 1.44,
  252: 1.43,
  253: 1.4,
  254: 1.31,
  255: 1.31,
  256: 1.26,
  257: 1.26,
  258: 1.11,
  259: 1.01,
  260: 1.01,
  261: 1.0,
  262: 0.98,
  263: 0.94,
  264: 0.9,
  265: 0.85,
  266: 0.8,
  267: 0.78,
  268: 0.75,
  269: 0.66,
  270: 0.61,
  271: 0.55,
  272: 0.49,
  273: 0.46,
  274: 0.41,
  275: 0.37,
  276: 0.34,
  277: 0.3,
  278: 0.0,
  279: 0.0,
  280: 0.0,
  281: 0.0,
  282: 0.0,
  283: 0.0,
  284: 0.0,
  285: 0.0,
  286: 0.0,
  287: 0.0,
  288: 0.0,
  289: 0.0,
  290: 0.0,
  291: 0.0,
  292: 0.0,
  293: 0.0,
  294: 0.0,
  295: 0.0,
  296: 0.0,
  297: 0.0,
  298: 0.0,
  299: 0.0,
  300: 0.0,
  301: 0.0,
  302: 0.0,
  303: 0.0,
  304: 0.0,
  305: 0.0,
  306: 0.0,
  307: 0.0,
  308: 0.0,
  309: 0.0,
  310: 0.0,
  311: 0.0}}
```

Comment: Please use `df. to_dict()` and post the output here so we can reproduce your df

Comment: It exceeds the no. of characters in the body of the question. Can I add the dataset as a link?

Comment: try and get a sample of your dataset, and then use ```df.to_dict()``` instead of pasting as a link please.

Comment: maybe first `groupby`  `'Hour','Minute'` and later use some `.count()` or `.count_values()` to count `NAN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand it but you can `groupby` `'Hour','Minute'` and count `NaN` in every group and `drop` this group

```
all_groups = df.groupby(['Hour', 'Minute'])

for name, group in all_groups:
    count = group['Voltage'].isna().sum()
    #print('name:', name, 'count:', count)
    if count > 5:
        df.drop(group.index, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropna(axis=0) function for deleting rows but without seeing your dataframe I cannot help with the conditioning.

Comment: This is how the dataframe looks like: {'Date': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
 'Hour': {0: 6, 1: 6, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 6},
 'Minute': {0: 0, 1: 5, 2: 10, 3: 15, 4: 20},
 'Voltage': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}}